# como cambiar el tamaño de la linea divisora de un menu lateral

Tags: android, android-studio

quisiera lograr este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo la siguiente foto como resultado y no puedo achicar el tamaño de la linea divisora y cambiar el color

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<group
    android:id="@+id/menu_top"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/clientInformation"
        android:title="@string/clientInformation" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/updatePass"
        android:title="@string/updatePassword" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/associate_disassociate"
        android:title="@string/associate_disassociateAccount" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:title="@string/" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/closeSession"
        android:title="@string/button_closesession" />
</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/menu_bottoms"
    android:checkableBehavior="none">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/da"
        android:title="@string/button_closesession" />
</group>
```

ese es el xml que uso para armar el menu con los items

Comment: Yo te podría ayudar con el cambio de color. Con respecto al tamaño no sabría decirte.

Comment: gracias, pero por lo que vi no se puede ajustar eso.. Muchas gracias igual.

Comment: Supongo que habría que crear una nueva clase y hacerla de tipo NavigationView particular. Pero eso debe de llevar bastante trabajo. Saludos!

Comment: Lo pude resolver con una listView, me resulto mucho mejor de esta manera. Gracias!

Comment: si alguien le sirve la respuesta, cree un listview donde agrege un relative por cada items y  le agrege a ese listview un header y un footer por separado.